# JTreeTable display problem

Tags: java, swing, listener, swingx, jtreetable

I've the following problem..
I've created a JTreeTable and a model which extends AbstractTreeTableModel.
The problem is that my data are shown only if I call the                    fireTreeStructureChanged() method after each inserting operation. In fact if I simple fire the method fireTreeNodesInserted(), nothing happens.

Besides, the data in my row are updated only after an add/remove event, if they simple change their value they are updated only after a click on the table.

How is it possible?

*EDIT*

When I call  fireTreeStructureChanged() then it calls the method fireTableDataChanged(); instead the fireTreeNodesInserted(int firstRow, int lastRow) calls     fireTableRowsInserted(); but maybe I pass to it the incorrect parameters...which first and last row I have to pass?

Comment: dumb question, but are you sure you're including the correct indices and paths when using the `fireTreeNodesInserted()` method?

Comment: Right observation...how can I check this?Becasue I'm not sure that I've understood how I have to fill these array...I try with an example: I have a root node R, then I first add a node A, then A1 to A and finally B to R. A very short and simple structure. The root node is inserted when I create the table passing the model. For the adding of the node A to R, I call fireTreeNodesInserted(R, path, index, A); can you explain me the correct parameters?thank you!

Comment: most probably, you do the firing wrong (it's a bit confusing, best explanation is in api doc TreeEvent, from the top of my head) Have a look at DefaultTreeModel for a working example

Answer (score 1):

To alleviate the pain of event firing, [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net) has a helper class TreeModelSupport which is usable independent of the project

**Edit**

that *is* the standard way :-) A well tested 1:1 mapping of api doc in TreeModelEvent and TreeModelListener, reading it will help you understand.

Comment: I also recommend using the SwingX helper class or better, a JXTreeTable instead of the JTreeTable, which is a real pain.